# Download and import file from web directly into R environment

Tags: r

I was trying to import a hotel reviews dataset into R from website. How do we do this one line of code, without manually downloading it and then importing it using read.csv type functions?

https://data.world/datafiniti/hotel-reviews/workspace/file?filename=Datafiniti_Hotel_Reviews.csv

Clicking on the above link doesn't directly prompt you to download. I tried using the URL function within read.csv().

Thanks for your help.

Rahman

Answer (score 1):

you need to go to the "share url" in Data World to get the proper link

```
url2<-"https://query.data.world/s/hvrhbuqej6z2wdlmga4vtpsxx32ig4"
download.file(url2, destfile = "./Data.csv",cacheOK=TRUE) 
Data<-read.csv("./Data.csv",header=T,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the answer above, but you can also f you click on the **Download** button in data.world and click on **Share URL**, you can copy a one-liner for R to load that table directly from the signed URL:
[image]